# Power BI DAX - RANKX Duplicated Rank

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to show the top 10 URLs based on views in a Power BI report, but I have an issue with RANKX since the rank is duplicated for rows with the same number of views.

The purpose is to only show up to 10 URLs based on rank.

[image]

Below is the RANKX code that I am using.

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL('Articles Monthly'[Page URL]),'Articles Monthly'[TotalPageViews])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to arbitrarily break ties, then you could create a tie breaking column using the [RAND()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rand-function-dax) function. Then rank based on that column.

```
Tie Breaker = 'Articles Monthly'[TotalPageViews] + RAND()
```

then

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL('Articles Monthly'),'Articles Monthly'[Tie Breaker])
```

If your problem is that, after a tie, the rank sequence continues directly to the next number such as follows:

Ex. You have RankDense, when you instead want RankSkip.

**RankDense:** 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3

**RankSkip:** 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9

Then just add a fifth parameter of "Skip" to the [RANKX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax) function.

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL('Articles Monthly'[Page URL]),'Articles Monthly'[TotalPageViews], , , "Skip")
```

Comment: Is there any way to return the Rank as follows
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: @Marc I've updated my answer. Please see if this solves your problem and accept/like it if it does.

Comment: unfortunately, the same problem there
2,2,4,3,4,9,8,8,7

Comment: Are you using the top 

    Rank = RANKX(ALL('Articles Monthly'[Page URL]),'Articles Monthly'[TotalPageViews] + RAND()) 

code?

Comment: yes...
Rank = RANKX(ALL('Articles Monthly'[Page URL]),'Articles Monthly'[TotalPageViews] + RAND())

Comment: Gotcha gotcha. I'm sorry about that, it looks like you need an intermediary column. Please look at my updated answer.

Comment: Hello, did my answer solve your issue? If so would you mind accepting it as the solution and upvoting it?